# Commercial support for ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there companies or individuals that can or do provide commercial support for ROS. I.e. to help with specific components of ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63437/commercial-support-for-ros/) by [Greg S](https://answers.ros.org/users/4943/greg-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a good list. SwRI is my favorite ;)

http://www.osrfoundation.org/consultants-network/

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2